# Can not attach chosen plugin to asp.net mvc 4 site

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen

I have been trying to attach this http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ to my asp.net mvc 4 site, but still to no avail. 
I tried doing the same with simple WebForms, and it was a success.
Nuget packages were downloaded to default locations in both cases.
in all I downloaded these packages:

- Jquery-2.1.1
- Jquery-ui-1.10.4
- chosen-1.1.0
- chosen.jquery-1.1.0

Scripts are located in `/Scripts` folder and Css file in `/Content`
I have been using Visual Studio 2013.
Here is the code of View (simplified):

```
@model IEnumerable<modelnamehere>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TestedController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    some code here;
}

    <select multiple class="mySelector" data-placeholder="Choose...">
    <option>Select 1</option>
    <option>Select 2</option>
    <option>Select 3</option>
</select>


<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/chosen.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".mySelector").chosen();
    })
</script>
```

And here is `_Layout.cshtml` shared page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - ASP.NET MVC</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("ASP.NET MVC", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                    </section> 
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Testing Page", "Index","TestedController")/li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - ASP.Net MVC</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

I`m kinda new to using JQuery, so if there is some explanation to the wrongs steps I have done, it would be much app

Comment: shouldn't this: `~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js` be this: `~/Scripts/chosen.jquery-1.1.0.js`? and you may need to wrap the scripts in a scripts section so that it appears after your jquery is included otherwise your document ready won't work, better still why not include the scripts and css as part of your bundles

Comment: No. the chosen plugin has the name of `chosen.jquery.js`. Thanks. I put the plugin and css in bundles, and set it before the content page and it worked.